# Is there any way to load ApplicationUser some columns only?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a Post model Class with relation to ApplicationUser Model.From controller when i made eager loading ApplicationUsers all data loaded here. i dont want to load Users password.I wanted to load users some columns data only.

ModeL Class :

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }        
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }      
}
```

controller:

```
var Post = await _context.Post.Include(x=>x.Client).ToListAsync();
```

Note: I used .Net Core Indentity  .

Thanks for read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can select only some properties of `.Client`. You could however use a dto:

```
 var PostDto = await _context.Post
    //.Where
    .Select( p => new PostDTo {
        PostId,
        PostContent, 
        Username = p.Client.UserName
 })
 .ToListAsync();
```

or

```
 var PostDto = await _context.Post
    //.Where
    .Select( p => new PostDTO {
        PostId,
        PostContent, 
        User = new UserDTO 
        { 
           p.Client.UserName,
           ...
        }
 })
 .ToListAsync();
```

Please note that by using DTOs rather then exposing tables you guarantee that the unwanted data is never exposed.

Comment: i was not concerned about DTOs . Now i completed my task. Thanks for help.
#stay safe.